# signalR service throws TLS protocol related error

Tags: ssl, signalr

I have self-hosted signalR service using Asp Net signalR 2.2.0 Nuget pacakge, the service is secured with SSL certificate with sha1 hash algorithm, the certificate includes an RSA public key, and is signed by a recognized CA that the client trusts. Certificate is configured and added to that port using **netsh http add sslcert** command successfully.

I get the following error while accessing signalR hub Uri - https://127.0.0.1:1234/signalr/hubs

**Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://127.0.0.1:1234 again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator**

Looks like connection uses TLS 1.0 protocol using obsolete cipher suite

Question -

(1) does self hosted service advertises the SSL/TLS protocols that it supports?
(2) can we setup the protocol when we start the signalR service? Ex- use TLS 2.0 instead of 1.0 something like that?

Comment: can you please check if TLS is enabled on the server
http://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having this same issue right now.

Comment: This is how I was able to solve my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38061978/279516